# Change style of specific element within *ngFor without class

Tags: angular

I have a template like this:

```
<div>
    <span class="tag label label-primary" *ngFor="let tag of tags">
        {{ tag }}
    </span>
</div>
```

I have a function `addTag(tag)` inside my component which only allows for a tag to be added to the array, if it doesn't already exist.

```
private addTag(tag) {
    // Checks if the tag is empty or only consists of whitespace
    // or is already in tags array
    if (tag.replace(/\s/g, "").length == 0 || _.contains(this.tags, tag))
        return;

    this.tags.push(tag.trim());
}
```

If the user tries to add a tag that already exists, I want to flash(set opacity to zero and increase it with setInterval) the already existing tag.

How do I change the opacity of the correct span element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<span [ngClass]="{flash:i==flashIndex}" class="tag" *ngFor="let tag of tags;let i = index">
  {{ tag }}
</span>
...
flashIndex: number;
tags: Array<string> = [];
addTag(tagInput) {
  let tag = tagInput.value;
  if (!tag.replace(/\s/g, "").length) return;

  const existedItem = this.tags.find(x => x === tag); 

  if (existedItem) {
     this.flashIndex = this.tags.indexOf(existedItem);
     setTimeout(()=> this.flashIndex = -1, 1000);
     return;
  }

  this.tags.push(tag.trim());
  tagInput.value = '';
}
```

See corresponding [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PxTlPiNjTSEbZc3mnlYO?p=preview)

Comment: Ah, very clever thanks! 
One addition: The `#i = index` probably should be `let i = index` right?

Comment: @ChristopherStöckl Maybe you're right. I saw here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html#!#syntax

Comment: Yes, I implemented your answer and it told me in the console that the use of `#` is deprecated and should be `let`. I'm using version 2.0.0-beta.17 of angular2.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    <span [style.opacity]="flash" class="tag label label-primary" *ngFor="let tag of tags">
        {{ tag }}
    </span>
</div>
```

The value of the `flash` property in your component class will be set on the elements style.

Alternative:

```
<div>
    <span [ngStyle]="{opacity:flash}" class="tag label label-primary" *ngFor="let tag of tags">
        {{ tag }}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have already tried that and it doesn't work, because it sets this style on ALL the spans. I need to target a specific one.

Comment: You can make `flash` an array or object and use `{opacity: flash[x]}` where `x` could be `tag` or the `index` from `ngFor` or whatever works for you.